# Регулярное выражение как указать исключение из результата

Tags: php

Всем привет. Суть такова есть регулярное выражение которое ищет все даты в тексте и делает их красными если за ними идет слово месяц допусти (30 января).
как сделать что бы января не попадала в результат замены. То есть была в шаблоне поиска и искала все даты за которыми идет только месяц но в результе не учитывала месяц а выводил только дату перед месяцем. Как исключить из результата месяц что бы форматировать только дату. Вот код приблизительно:

````
```  $string=$_POST ["formText"];
//Подчеркиваем даты жирным кирпичным цветом
$pattern = '/\s+\d+\s*(январ|сентя|феврал|март|апрел|мая|июн|июл|август|сентяб|октяб|декабр).*?\s+/';
$replacement = '<strong style="color: darkred; font-weight: bold">$0</strong>';
$resultData=preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string,-1);```
````

Данный код красным делает полностью 30 и января.

Comment: А смысл искать чтоб потом не "форматировать"?

Comment: Найти надо и отформатировать только числа за которыми идти должны месяца

Answer (score 0):

Типа так:

```
$string = $_POST ["formText"];
$pattern = '/(\d{1,2})(\s*?)(январ|феврал|март|апрел|мая|июн|июл|август|сентяб|октяб|ноябр|декабр)(.*?)/i';
$replacement = '<strong style="color: darkred; font-weight: bold">$1</strong>$2$3$4';
$resultData=preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

https://onlinegdb.com/pZJN8eyzD

Comment: `$2$3$4` одной группой то не записать? и главное вообще нужно ли их тут упоминать?

Comment: Тут проблема что в тексте мы не знаем сколько будет совпадений может пять дат а может две а может 12 и прописывать $1 $2 $3 на каждое совпадение не вариант

Comment: STAS ST: хоть сто: https://onlinegdb.com/8vRvzw6mp

Comment: teran: можно взять их в скобки все, тогда они будут выступать одной переменной в замене, но не так наглядно, да и вложенности скобок лучше избегать. Вообще без них нельзя ибо будет заменять все "11 января сего года", например, на подчеркнутое 11.

Comment: "декабр" -- слишком общо: "13 июля казнили 5 декабристов"

Comment: @Егор Банин: я лишь скопировал и чуть подправил. Все месяцы было лень править, неудобно лежа мышей по экр. клав.

Comment: хоть сто: onlinegdb.com/8vRvzw6mp – 
Zombotron да спасибо теперь понял что это тоже работает.

Comment: Всем большое спасибо: Zombotron, Егор Банин и всем остальным.  Разобрался - утверждения и номера подмасок вот что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Есть пара способов сделать это.

1. Регулярки на PHP поддерживают [*утверждения*](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.assertions.php).

```
\d{1,2}(?=\s*(января|февраля|марта|апреля|мая|июня|июля|августа|сентября|октября|ноября|декабря)(\W|$))

<b>$0</b>
```

2. Можно использовать [*номера подмасок*](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php) при подстановке.

```
(\d{1,2})(\s*(?:января|февраля|марта|апреля|мая|июня|июля|августа|сентября|октября|ноября|декабря)(?:\W|$))

<b>$1</b>$2
```

Обратите внимание, что в вашей регулярке пропал ноябрь. Так же строка начинающаяся с числа и заканчивающаяся числом не будет сматчена (например: "14 сентября -- день государственного гимна США.", "В Никарагуа день победы отмечают 14 сентября.").

Comment: Утверждения для  PHP это то что я искал спасибо большое. Номера подмасок то же тема классная.

Comment: @STASST чтобы не срабатывало ложно на строки типа "2 маяка", можно добавить проверку на `\W|$`. Чтобы \W правильно работала, не забудьте модификатор `u`.